# How to subset data based on pattern of rows?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some messy data that looks like this.

```
id          V1    
Player   Score
Kevin        8
Michael      7
Ralf         2
NA
Player   Value
Kevin        6
Michael      1
Ralf         2
NA
```

I would like to subset the data based on this pattern where NA (missing value) acts like an indicator for the end of a table.

I’m trying to split them like this to a list made of separate dataframes:

```
Player   Score
Kevin        8
Michael      7
Ralf         2
```

```
Player    Value
Kevin        6
Michael      1
Ralf         2
```

Comment: Is it a flat text file, or already parsed as a two-column data frame? (It's helpful to post data as code, like with `dput()`, to avoid such ambiguities.)

Comment: It’s already parsed as a two column dataframe.

Comment: Are the column headers id/V1 or Player/Value? You might want to skip the first row on import if you don't want those to be the column headers.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  mutate(group = cumsum(lag(is.na(id), default = TRUE))) %>%
  filter(id != "Player") %>%
  group_split(group)
```

using this data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                id = c("Player","Kevin","Michael",
                       "Ralf",NA,"Player","Kevin","Michael","Ralf",NA),
                V1 = c("Score", "8", "7", "2", NA, "Value", "6", "1", "2", NA)
)
```

result:

```
<list_of<
  tbl_df<
    id   : character
    V1   : character
    group: integer
  >
>[2]>
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  id      V1    group
  <chr>   <chr> <int>
1 Kevin   8         1
2 Michael 7         1
3 Ralf    2         1

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  id      V1    group
  <chr>   <chr> <int>
1 Kevin   6         2
2 Michael 1         2
3 Ralf    2         2
```

Comment: This is cool! Would it be possible to retain the column names like Score and Value? They are quite unique.